# allow user to select pages from dropdown in my plugin

Tags: php, plugin-development

I have a plugin and a part in it allows user to select the page plugin works on by specifying the id of the page. But I want that he should be able to select the page from the pages available in the website.

This can be implemented by a drop down or check boxes.

my code looks like this in the main file of plugin :

```
register_setting( 'rex_plug_options', 'rex_plug_options', 'rex_plug_settings_validate' );
add_settings_field('rex_plugbox_text_exit_pop_selected_pages', 'Select Pages (comma seprated page ID E.G.:  12,32,434)', 'rex_plugbox_text_exit_pop_selected_pages', 'rex_plug_box', 'rex_plug_main_box');
<?php
}
function rex_plugbox_text_exit_pop_selected_pages(){
global $rex_plug_options;
if(!isset($rex_plug_options["rex_plugbox_text_exit_pop_selected_pages"]))   {
    $rex_plug_options["rex_plugbox_text_exit_pop_selected_pages"] = "";
}
?>
    <textarea id="rex_plugbox_text_exit_pop_selected_pages" type="text" name="rex_plug_options[rex_plugbox_text_exit_pop_selected_pages]" ><?php echo sanitize_text_field( $rex_plug_options["rex_plugbox_text_exit_pop_selected_pages"] ); ?></textarea>

<?php
}
```

Now this works with the text area and all I want it to be a dropdown. how can I do that ?

I tried doing this :

```
 <select name="rex_plug_options[page_id]">
                        <?php
                        if( $pages = get_pages() ){
                            foreach( $pages as $page ){
                                echo '<option value="' . $page->ID . '" ' . selected( $page->ID, $options['page_id'] ) . '>' . $page->post_title . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
```

this display the select field but not sure how to update the database option array field with what is selected in this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
register_setting( 'rex_plug_options', 'rex_plug_options', 'rex_plug_settings_validate' );
add_settings_field('rex_plugbox_text_exit_pop_selected_pages', 'Select Pages', 'rex_plugbox_text_exit_pop_selected_pages', 'rex_plug_box', 'rex_plug_main_box');
//with selectbox you cannot select multiple pages. If you need that try checkbox

function rex_plugbox_text_exit_pop_selected_pages(){
    global $rex_plug_options;
    if(!isset($rex_plug_options["rex_plugbox_text_exit_pop_selected_pages"]))   {
        $rex_plug_options["rex_plugbox_text_exit_pop_selected_pages"] = "";
    }
?>
    <select id="rex_plugbox_text_exit_pop_selected_pages" name="rex_plug_options[rex_plugbox_text_exit_pop_selected_pages]">
    <?php
    if( $pages = get_pages() ){
        foreach( $pages as $page ){
            echo '<option value="' . $page->ID . '" ' . selected( $page->ID, $rex_plug_options["rex_plugbox_text_exit_pop_selected_pages"] ) . '>' . $page->post_title . '</option>';
        }
    }
    ?>
    </select>
<?php
}
```

Comment: I am using it on a plugin io the backend, what does after the form submitted means ?

Comment: @RishiRajPurohit Where does user get the option to select page? After selecting the page, don't they submit a form? How do you get the selected page?

Comment: its a plugin with options, once they write their id they can submit. The page-id gets saved in database. I want them to have a dropdown where they can select page

Comment: @RishiRajPurohit Check my edit. I think if your textarea method works, this should work too. You should understand that I don't have any idea how your plugin works.

Comment: its fine and thanks for your valuable time, I figured it out . I was missing the name field of select. Anyhow you know where I can learn about tag system. you type word a ajax dropdown shows possible values and then you select one and you get option to select more than one

Comment: @RishiRajPurohit I don't exactly understand what you mean. Maybe create a separate question with proper explanation of what you want to accomplish.